# I don't see why my :last-child selector isn't working as it should be

Tags: html, css

In my CSS I've used wrapped divs class to call last-child to remove the right margin, but for some reason I can't find the problem.

```css
.user-panel {
  border-bottom-color: #8F8F8F;
  background-color: #FCFCFC;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #D9D9D9;
  float: left;
  width: 257px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  border-bottom-color: #8F8F8F;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.user-panel-wrap:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.user-panel:hover {
  background-color: #B2D195;
}

.user-panel-image {
  margin: 5px auto;
  display: block;
}

.user-panel-header {
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
}

.user-panel-paragraph {
  color: #A0A09E;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 19px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="user-panel-wrap">
  <a class="user-panel-link" href="#">
    <div class="user-panel">
      <img class="user-panel-image" src="pictures/tockici.jpg">
      <p class="user-panel-header">SERVICES</p>
      <p class="user-panel-paragraph">It's what we do!</p>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="user-panel-link" href="#">
    <div class="user-panel">
      <img src="pictures/cart.png" alt="" class="user-panel-image">
      <p class="user-panel-header">ORDER</p>
      <p class="user-panel-paragraph">Start the process!</p>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="user-panel-link" href="#">
    <div class="user-panel">
     <img src="pictures/faq.png" alt="" class="user-panel-image">
      <p class="user-panel-header">FAQ</p>
      <p class="user-panel-paragraph">Find some answers</p>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="user-panel-link" href="#">
    <div class="user-panel">
      <img src="pictures/login.jpg" alt="" class="user-panel-image">
      <p class="user-panel-header">LOG IN</p>
      <p class="user-panel-paragraph">Current clients</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: `.user-panel-wrap:last-child` doesn't work in your stack snippet because an empty script element is inserted at the end, so it's no longer the last child. However, it shouldn't have a any margin, so `margin-right: 0` is pointless. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Im very new to this. So i puted margin because i need space between those divs, but last can't have it so it goes to the end of site-wrap. Thats why i tryied with last child to just change margin of the last div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:last-child` pseudo selector is applied on your wrapping div here. As a result you select the wrapper that is the last child of its parent. And because you only created one wrapper, you just select the only one you have.

I suspect that you want to select the last child of this wrapper. To do this, you need to do `.user-panel-wrap > :last-child`.
And because I also suspect that you want to set the margin not of the `<a>` tag but on the `.user-panel`, you should actually do `.user-panel-wrap > :last-child .user-panel`.

```css
.user-panel {
  border-bottom-color: #8F8F8F;
  background-color: #FCFCFC;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #D9D9D9;
  float: left;
  width: 257px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  border-bottom-color: #8F8F8F;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.user-panel-wrap > :last-child .user-panel {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.user-panel:hover {
  background-color: #B2D195;
}

.user-panel-image {
  margin: 5px auto;
  display: block;
}

.user-panel-header {
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
}

.user-panel-paragraph {
  color: #A0A09E;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 19px;
}
```

```html
<div class="user-panel-wrap">
  <a class="user-panel-link" href="#">
    <div class="user-panel">
      <img class="user-panel-image" src="pictures/tockici.jpg">
      <p class="user-panel-header">SERVICES</p>
      <p class="user-panel-paragraph">It's what we do!</p>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="user-panel-link" href="#">
    <div class="user-panel">
      <img src="pictures/cart.png" alt="" class="user-panel-image">
      <p class="user-panel-header">ORDER</p>
      <p class="user-panel-paragraph">Start the process!</p>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="user-panel-link" href="#">
    <div class="user-panel">
     <img src="pictures/faq.png" alt="" class="user-panel-image">
      <p class="user-panel-header">FAQ</p>
      <p class="user-panel-paragraph">Find some answers</p>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="user-panel-link" href="#">
    <div class="user-panel">
      <img src="pictures/login.jpg" alt="" class="user-panel-image">
      <p class="user-panel-header">LOG IN</p>
      <p class="user-panel-paragraph">Current clients</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes i made user-panel-wrap just to be parent, so i can select last div and remove his margin-right. I wrote ur type of solution, and margin right is still there. Thanks for the answer tho. :)

Comment: I removed the margin of the child (i.e. the last `<a>` tag). But apparently what you really want is to suppress the margin on the panel. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you man, this worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.user-panel-link:last-child .user-panel {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Hope this solution works for you ☝️

```css
.user-panel {
  border-bottom-color: #8F8F8F;
  background-color: #FCFCFC;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #D9D9D9;
  float: left;
  width: 257px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  border-bottom-color: #8F8F8F;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.user-panel:hover {
  background-color: #B2D195;
}
.user-panel-image {
  margin: 5px auto;
  display: block;
}
.user-panel-header {
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
}
.user-panel-paragraph {
  color: #A0A09E;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 19px;
}
.user-panel-link:last-child .user-panel {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="user-panel-wrap">
  <a class="user-panel-link" href="#">
    <div class="user-panel">
      <img class="user-panel-image" src="pictures/tockici.jpg">
      <p class="user-panel-header">SERVICES</p>
      <p class="user-panel-paragraph">It's what we do!</p>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="user-panel-link" href="#">
    <div class="user-panel">
      <img src="pictures/cart.png" alt="" class="user-panel-image">
      <p class="user-panel-header">ORDER</p>
      <p class="user-panel-paragraph">Start the process!</p>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="user-panel-link" href="#">
    <div class="user-panel">
      <img src="pictures/faq.png" alt="" class="user-panel-image">
      <p class="user-panel-header">FAQ</p>
      <p class="user-panel-paragraph">Find some answers</p>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="user-panel-link" href="#">
    <div class="user-panel">
      <img src="pictures/login.jpg" alt="" class="user-panel-image">
      <p class="user-panel-header">LOG IN</p>
      <p class="user-panel-paragraph">Current clients</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

:last-child is not working because .user-panel-wrap is the wrapper not the child selector. :last-child needs to be on the child, like this:

```
.parent-wrapper .child-name:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px; 
}
```

However, since you have .user-panel wrapped in a.user-panel-link, that will not work either. Try something like this:

```
<div class="user-panel-wrap">
    <div class="user-panel">
        <a class="user-panel-link" href="#">
            <img class="user-panel-image" src="pictures/tockici.jpg">
            <p class="user-panel-header">SERVICES</p>
            <p class="user-panel-paragraph">It's what we do!</p>
        </a>  
    </div>
    <div class="user-panel">
        <a class="user-panel-link" href="#">
            <img src="pictures/cart.png" alt="" class="user-panel-image">
            <p class="user-panel-header">ORDER</p>
            <p class="user-panel-paragraph">Start the process!</p>
        </a>  
    </div>
    <div class="user-panel">
        <a class="user-panel-link" href="#">
            <img src="pictures/faq.png" alt="" class="user-panel-image">
            <p class="user-panel-header">FAQ</p>
            <p class="user-panel-paragraph">Find some answers</p>
        </a>  
    </div>
    <div class="user-panel">
        <a class="user-panel-link" href="#">
            <img src="pictures/login.jpg" alt="" class="user-panel-image">
            <p class="user-panel-header">LOG IN</p>
            <p class="user-panel-paragraph">Current clients</p>
        </a>  
    </div>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
.user-panel-wrap .user-panel:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: It does clean last childs margin, but also does for all divs, for some reason, even if told just for last-child.

Comment: Did you use the new html?